# spring security (3.0.x) and user impersonation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, impersonation

In my web application, there are times when an authenticated admin might want to impersonate another valid user of a system without having to know that user's password.

How can I use Spring Security to give admin users the ability to impersonate normal (non-admin) users of the system?

The Spring Security documentation is silent on this and I can't find anything anywhere.  Surely someone must have solved this.

Thanks!

Comment: I was reading the docs the other day...didn't they talk about RunAs? Check out the docs and see if that is relevant to you

Answer (score 5):

It's in the [Spring Security 3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/runas.html) and [Spring Security 4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#runas) docs aptly named, "Run-As Authentication Replacement."

> The AbstractSecurityInterceptor is able to temporarily replace the Authentication object in the SecurityContext and SecurityContextHolder during the secure object callback phase.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the recommended way to do this in Spring Security is with the Domain Access Control lists, see GrantedAuthoritySid @

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/domain-acls.html

However, impersonating another user is more than just having a "delegate identity", you should also consider the implications on logging:

- Do you want your logging to appear as Original User or Impersonated User (or both?)
- Do you want the "impersonation" to show only what the impersonated user sees, or the superset of permissions of the Original User and Impersonated User?

Yet another possibility is to create a "log in as" feature, which essentially changes the principal identity of the current session - or starts a new session with the impersonated identity.

In all of the above, you may inadvertantly open up a security issue - so I think this is why impersonate-style features are not that common place.  Rather, designs trend towards Role Based Access Control (RBAC) or Attribute Based Access Control (ABAC).  Using RBAC / ABAC, you could create a delegate style feature where you create delegate attributes/roles - and in the special cases where you need to show the source/target of the delegation (e.g. for audit logs), you handle those as corner cases.

Comment: Nice answer.  I would guess he wants to do the "log in as" feature.

Comment: You could also register other SpEL functions so you can say something like hasRole('X') && !isImpersonating() to prevent admin users who are impersonating others from seeing sensitive data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an admin user to be able to impersonate another user (eg for QA/Testing purposes), have a look at the SwitchUserFilter

A decent example of the XML config you need is provided [here](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/user-impersonation-with-spring-and-ldap.html)