# How can I allow a user override with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring MVC web application, there are certain areas accessible only to users with sufficient privileges. Rather than just have a "access denied" message, I need to be able to allow users to log in as a different user in order to use these pages (sort of like an override).

How can I do this with Spring Security?

Here's the flow I am looking to have, with a bit more detail:

1. User A comes in to page X from external application and is authenticated via headers
2. User A does not have permission to use page X, and so is taken to the login screen with a message indicating that they must log in as a user with sufficient privilages to use this page
3. User B logs in, and has sufficient privilages, and is taken to page X.

Note: Page X has a big, long query string that needs to be preserved.

How can I do this with Spring Security?

---

Here's my spring security config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <debug />

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <!-- AspectJ pointcut expression that locates our "post" method and applies 
            security that way <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* bigbank.*Service.post*(..))" 
            access="ROLE_TELLER"/> -->
    </global-method-security>

    <!-- Allow anyone to get the static resources and the login page by not applying the security filter chain -->
    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/img/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />

    <!-- Lock everything down -->
    <http 
        auto-config="true"
        use-expressions="true" 
        disable-url-rewriting="true">

        <!-- Define the URL access rules -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/about/**" access="permitAll and !hasRole('blocked')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="hasRole('user')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/reviews/new**" access="hasRole('reviewer')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('user')" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" />

        <logout logout-url="/logout" /> 

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/login?reason=accessDenied"/>

        <!-- Limit the number of sessions a user can have to only 1 -->
        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
        </session-management>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="adAuthenticationProvider" />
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="superadmin" password="superadminpassword" authorities="user" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="adAuthenticationProvider" class="[REDACTED Package].NestedGroupActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="[REDACTED FQDN]" />
        <beans:constructor-arg value="[REDACTED LDAP URL]" />
        <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="[REDACTED Group Sub-Tree DN]" />
        <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="peerReviewLdapUserDetailsMapper" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="peerReviewLdapUserDetailsMapper" class="[REDACTED Package].PeerReviewLdapUserDetailsMapper">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="UserDAO" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

I'm using a slightly modified version of the Spring Security 3.1 Active Directory connection capabilities. The modifications simply load *all* of a user's groups, including those reached by group nesting, rather than only the ones the user is directly a member of. I'm also using a custom user object that has my application's User object embedded in it, and a custom LDAP mapper that does the normal LDAP mapping, and then adds in my user.

There is a special authentication scenario that has not been implemented yet where the user is authenticated based on a username passed from an external application (or via Kerberos) in a Single-Sign-On fashion.

Comment: Different use case, but related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337825/spring-security-3-0-x-and-user-impersonation .

Comment: @BarendGarvelink - Yes, I saw that, but I'm not looking to temporarily "pretend" to be another user. What I am looking to do is to allow them to effectively re-authenticate as a different user (essentially a logout-login) and then continue on to the page they were trying to access but could not.

Answer (score 2):

How do you check for roles ?

If you define them in your security context like this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/adminStuff.html**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

You can set the `defaultFailureUrl` in your [`SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.html) and when a user with lesser privileges tries to access a secured URL the `FaliureHandler` should redirect you to the `defaultFailureUrl` which could be your login page.

You can inject a `FaliureHandler` in the [filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) at the `FORM_LOGIN_FILTER` position.

```
<bean id="myFaliureHandler" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="http://yourdomain.com/your-login.html"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myFilter"
   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
   <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="myFaliureHandler"/>
</bean>    

<http>
  <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myFilter" />
</http>
```

---

Answering 1) in the comment.

This would be a little more work than I thought given your namespace configuration.

What you need to do is remove the `<form-login>` definition and instead of it add a 'custom' `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` (this is the filter that handles the `<form-login>` element).

You also need to remove the `<access-denied-handler>`.

So your configuration would look something like:

```
<bean id="myFaliureHandler" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="http://yourdomain.com/your-login.html"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myFilter"
   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
   <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="myFaliureHandler"/>
   <!-- there are more required properties, but you can read about them in the docs -->
</bean>

<bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
   <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
</bean>

<http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="false">

  <!-- your other http config goes here, just omit the form-login element and the access denied handler -->

  <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myFilter" />
</http>
```

Generally also have a look at the [spring docs on custom filters](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/core-web-filters.html), if you haven't already. We currently use this config in my current company forcing users to relogin if the don't have required privileges on a page.

Comment: I have a couple questions: 1.) Using the namespace configuration (see my edits above), where would I hook this in? 2.) The _authentication_ isn't the failure point, it's the _authorization_. The under-privileged user needs to be able to log in and do things, but when they try to do admin things, they would get prompted to log in with a higher -privileged user. Would this do that?

Comment: @cdeszaq 1) I'll edit my asnwer. 2) Yes this would do that, users with lesser roles will be asked to authenticate again.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Register an application wide [ExeptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) using anyway you like. For ex.

```
public class MyApplicationErrorResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver {

    @Autowired
    private List<LogoutHandler> logoutHandlers;

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {

        if(ex instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            for(LogoutHandler lh : logoutHandlers) {
                lh.logout(request, response, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
            }
            // Not present as a bean. So create it manually.
            SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
            logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
            logoutHandler.logout(request, response, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());

            return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(request.getRequestURL().toString()));
        }

        return super.doResolveException(request, response, handler, ex);
    }
}
```

register it as a bean:

```
<bean class="package.path.MyApplicationErrorResolver" />
```

(that's all you need to register it). This will work for your configuration. Bu you will probably need to remove the `<access-denied-handler>` element from the config.

**Solution 2**

Another way is to use an [AccessDeniedHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html). For ex:

```
public class MyAccessDeniedExceptionHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Autowired
    private List<LogoutHandler> logoutHandlers;

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException {
        for(LogoutHandler lh : logoutHandlers) {
            lh.logout(request, response, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        }

        SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
        logoutHandler.logout(request, response, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());

        response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    }

}
```

register it as a bean:

```
<bean id="accesssDeniedHandler" class="package.path.MyAccessDeniedExceptionHandler" />
```

and specify it in your config:

```
<access-denied-handler ref="accesssDeniedHandler" />
```